# Publish code from visual studio 2015 to Azure

Tags: provider-hosted-app, azure

We have been hosting the provider hosted app on the Azure environment from Visual Studio 2015.But from today morning the below error is coming.

Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started. 
Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)

The Azure site is running.What could be the problem?

Comment: It's a connectivity issue between deployment source and destination. Could be an intermittent hiccup, could be an actual problem. In the case of an intermittent issue, a subsequent redeploy will work.